# Why are all my formulas in doxygen html output empty?

Tags: doxygen

when i generate the HTML output of the following doxygen-conforment comments the generated image seems to be correctly sized but is completely empty/transparent. why?

```
/** \file */
/**
\mainpage main page

bla \f$(x_1,y_1)\f$ blub
*/
```

latex output seems to work fine and the Doxyfile used to work fine before too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `color` latex package changed over time and is loaded by the `EXTRA_PACKAGES` doxygen directive in the used Doxyfile like this: `EXTRA_PACKAGES         = bytefield ccaption color relsize`.`